# Include missing schemas in SOAP client using Zeep

Tags: python, soap, xsd, schema, zeep

We need to create a SOAP client using Python and Zeep library.

The responses obtained for some requests do not include expected fields. It looks like some namespace is missing to parse response content. Check next example:

```
    'DeviceMessage': {
                '_value_1': <Element {http://www.url.com/my/namespace_1}Temperature at 0x7fdd62dfaf40>
    }
```

We have some schema files (XSD) that define the structure for the Temperature object. How can we add them to the request to obtain the response correctly parsed?